# XAML reference data context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I am using PRISM to auto-wire my Views & ViewModels, however I have encountered a problem I cannot solve.

I am using a calendar control, which enables users to create new appointments via opening new modal window & saving it to calendar.

This window, is styled via a `ControlTemplate`, where I have the following item:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="3" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.EmployeeList}">
```

Items Source of this combobox is the ViewModels DataContext.EmployeeList - `ObservableCollection<Employee>`.

This would work like a charm as long as it would not be a new pop-out window. That way, I believe it is a userControl as well and therefore my regular code does not recognize any `EmployeeList`.

There might be 2 ways how to solve it (I don't have direct access to the modal window as it is being automatically generated by the control itself - I am using Telerik suite).

1) Make sure that the ItemsSource will dig deeper than the very first `UserControl` that it finds. Maybe by slightly changing the code, it will be able to do so? (Maybe using something like AncestorLevel...?).

2) Telerik has shown an example of how to achieve that by the following line:

```
<local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" /> -- define key first
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=EmployeesSource}"...
```

**BUT** the issue with my ViewModel is that under constructor I am passing several `interfaces` like following:

```
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
    public EmployeeView_HolidaysViewModel(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;

        InitializeCollections();
        InitializeCommands();
    }
```

and therefore I can't make the above solution to work at all.

Any help with my problem would be highly appreciated. I simply need to get that list to that modal window's combobox.

Comment: RelativeSource stinks.  I just use ElementName bindings.  Also, go look into TemplateBinding.  I'm not sure if it will help you in this case, but it might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to solve the problem by creating additional constructor to my class which looks like following:

```
    public EmployeeView_HolidaysViewModel()
    {
        _employeeRepository = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEmployeeRepository>();

        InitializeCollections();
    }
```

This way I can easily adopt  **Solution Nr 2** from the OP.